# Cisco VPN connection using CertStore as in Windows

Tags: vpn, certificates

In Windows I was using Cisco VPN client to connect with VPN. In connection properties I set only hostname and choose certificate which are stored in `C:\Program Files\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\Certificates`.

I moved yesterday to Ubuntu and I need to be able to connect with that host using those certificates too.

I know that there is `vpnc` and `network-manager-vpnc` but it not allows (or I do not know about it) to set cerificates dir.

Can someone tell me how to connect with VPN using certificates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the use of certificates but I use Cisco vpns for connecting to work and I just import the .pcf files into netowrk-manager and the connection works.
Perhaps you can try that.

Else you may try installing the Cisco VPN client from cisco for Linux. Here's the tutorial for that. http://blog.bitengine.ca/?p=107

Comment: I was importing `.pcf` file in the beginning but oryginal `.pcf` had configuration of storing certificates dir, it's name, etc and after importing, Linux's `.pcf` file has it cleaned. It does not respects all of the imported informations.